# Problem finding whether checkbox is checked inside jQuery each loop

Tags: jquery, checkbox, each

I was wondering whether anybody here could help with this problem I am having assigning a var value of 1 if a checkbox is checked and 0 if not checked inside a jQuery each loop.

I have a html list which looks like this:

```
<ul id="role-list">

<li id="role_1">
<p>Read<input type="checkbox" class="read"> Write<input type="checkbox" class="write"></p>
</li>

<li id="role_4">
<p>Read<input type="checkbox" class="read"> Write<input type="checkbox" class="write"></p>
</li>

<li id="role_5">
<p>Read<input type="checkbox" class="read"> Write<input type="checkbox" class="write"></p>
</li>

</ul>
```

I am trying to create a multidimensional array with jQuery using the following code:

```
var roles = {};
   $('#role-list li').each(function() {

   var role_id = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace('role_', '');

   roles[role_id] = {};
   $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {

    roles[role_id][jQuery(this).attr('class')] = $(this).checked ? 1 : 0;

});

});
    alert(JSON.stringify(roles));
```

Here is the output I am getting which is the same whether any check boxes are checked or not:

```
{"1":{"read":0,"write":0},"4":{"read":0,"write":0},"5":{"read":0,"write":0}}
```

The problem I am getting is that the code:

```
$(this).checked ? 1 : 0;
```

does not seem to work correctly. I have tried multiple variations to try and get this to work before posting but I am still having no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

.............

I eventually decided to remove the each loop for the checkboxes and use the following code which works correctly:

```
var roles = {};
   $('#role-list li').each(function() {

   var role_id = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace('role_', '');

   roles[role_id] = {};

   roles[role_id]['read'] = jQuery(this).find('.read').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;

   roles[role_id]['write'] = jQuery(this).find('.write').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0

});
```

Comment: Why are you using an object literal var `roles = {}` instead of an array `var roles = []`?

Comment: @Belinda - I have updated the question to show the output I am getting. Thanks

Comment: And which checkboxes are checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want

```
$(this).is(':checked')
-or-
$(this).attr('checked')
-or-
this.checked
```

or change your query to:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

in which case you don't need the ternary at all, which may be the better option since you're not filling roles with zeros (which you may want?)

`$(this).checked` doesn't exist because `$(this)` is a jquery object and `.checked` is an attribute of the individual element.

Comment: I have removed the code `$(this).checked ? 1 : 0` and tried all three of your suggestions but still cannot get this to work. I have also updated the question to show the output I am getting. Thanks

Comment: um, stupid question but are you sure any of them are checked?  :)  `:checked` works and is the proper way using jQuery.  This is one of those "if it's not working, something else is broken" times... I'm really not sure what to say...  What's the result of `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length`?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I have spent ages trying to figure out what is wrong with the code...Eventually I decide to remove the each loop for the checkboxes so I have added my updated code above with your method for selecting is checked